# Using slice() to only return the first 5 results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slice

Currently I have a site that when a button is clicked it returns the lastest movies and tv shows that are airing.

Right now the api I am using returns a whole page of values up to 20 results from my research of the api there is no limit function all i want to do is have 5 of those results be returned

I have been told that the slice() function may work.

Also any other why that you think my work would be nice aswell if you can figure out another way

I have included a jsfiddle but removed my api key

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/xvTe9/

Here's all my code just without my api key

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample Seach</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/',
    mode = 'movie/now_playing',
    input,
    movieName,
    key = '?api_key=API KEY HERE';

    $('#search').click(function() {
        var input = $('#titlesearch').val(),
            movieName = encodeURI(input);
        $.ajax({
            url: url + mode + key + '&query='+movieName' ,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(data) {

        var table = '<table>';
        $.each( data.results, function( key, value ) {
          table += '<tr><td class="results-img"><img src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500' + value.poster_path +'" alt="" width="130" height="150"></td><td class="results-title"><h4>' + value.original_title + '</h4></td></tr>';
        });
        $('#searchresult').html(table);
            }
        });
    });
});
// tv show search
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/',
    mode = 'tv/on_the_air',
    input,
    tvName,
    key = '?api_key=API KEY HERE';

    $('#search').click(function() {
        var input = $('#titlesearch').val(),
            tvName = encodeURI(input);
        $.ajax({
            url: url + mode + key + '&query='+tvName,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(data) {

        var table = '<table>';
        $.each( data.results, function( key, value ) {
          table += '<tr><td class="results-img"><img src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500' + value.poster_path +'" alt="" width="130" height="150"></td><td class="results-title"><h4>' + value.original_name + '</h4></td></tr>';
        });
        $('#searchresulttv').html(table);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
<script text="text/javascript">
// When the more button is click this runs a search using the title of the movie it is next to  
$('.results-img').live('click', '.results-img', function() {
    getImdbInfo( $(this).closest('tr').find('.results-title').text());
});

//The function below takes the entered title and searchs imdb for a match then it displays as followed

function getImdbInfo(Title) {
    var url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" + Title + "&plot=full";
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      cache: false,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      success: function(data) {

            var str = "";
            str += "<h2><center>Title :" +data.Title+ "</center></h2>";
            str += "<center><img src='" + data.Poster + "' /></center><br />";
            str += "<h4><center>Plot :</center></h4><p>" +data.Plot+ "</p>";

            $("#chosenresult").html(str);
      },
      error: function (request, status, error) { alert(status + ", " + error); }
    });
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h1>Movie and Tv Search</h1>
<button id="search">Search</button>
</center>
<div id="chosenresult"></div>
<div id="searchresult" style="float:left;"></div>
<div id="searchresulttv" style="float:right;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Screenshot of results that i want just the 5

[image]

Comment: If the api supports some kind of `limit` parameter I would rather use that one instead of the js slice. But I don't know if it does. Aren't you allready using something like that `&visible=5`?

Comment: sry that was left over it does not support any limit function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use slice to first reduce the array which must be iterated in the callback function of ajax.

```
var results = data.results.slice(0,5);
$.each(results, function( key, value ) {
          table += '<tr><td class="results-img"><img src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500' + value.poster_path +'" alt="" width="130" height="150"></td><td class="results-title"><h4>' + value.original_name + '</h4></td></tr>';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've stored the results in an array,

```
arr.slice(0,5)
```

will return the first five elements.

Comment: all the results are returned from an api source call tmdb each page is an array of 20 results i dont know how to access them i was told that slice might be what i need but i will try anything ?

Answer (score 0):

Using your current `$.each` you could do:

```
$.each(data.results, function (index, value) {
    table += '<tr>
                <td class="results-img">
                  <img src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500' + value.poster_path + '" alt="" width="130" height="150">
                </td>
                <td class="results-title">
                  <h4>' + value.original_name + '</h4>
                </td>
              </tr>';

   return (index !== 6);
});
```